# Angular (5) : Custom Dropdown Component

Tags: angular

Goal: The custom dropdown should accept any data as item source to bind to it.
Based on the object properties I am trying to set the `*ngFor` value for example
if the itemsource is an array of strings I can just say `*ngFor="let item in itemSource"`. Now if the itemSource is an object with properties without changing the `*ngFor=let item in itemSource`, how can I achieve it? Can I change the item value in `let item in itemSource` in component code?

```
 <select class="form-control" name="test1" [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="onModelChange($event.target.value)">
                  <option value="">Select state</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let item of itemSource"
                  [ngValue]="item.id" >{{item}}</option>
              </select>
```

Here is the plunk : https://plnkr.co/edit/xFvvJ559idGxQMhDD6Ya?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In your component, I assume you have an @input() property that you display in your Dropdown list right ?
From that assumption, let's look at this example :

```
@Input() initialItemSource;
itemSource;

ngOnInit(){
   if(this.initialItemSource){
      if(typeof this.initialItemSource === 'object' && typeof this.initialItemSource.length === "number"){
         let obj:any = {};
         this.initialItemSource.forEach((el,index) =>{
             obj[index] = el;            
         });
         this.itemSource = obj; //Now itemSource is an object;
      }else if(typeof this.initialItemSource === 'object'){
           this.itemSource =  this.initialItemSource;
      }
   }
}
```

now you need to consume your itemSource from the template

```
<select class="form-control" *ngIf="itemSource" name="test1" 
        [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="onModelChange($event.target.value)">
       <option value="">Select state</option>
       <option *ngFor="let item of itemSource" 
        [ngValue]="item" >itemSource[item]</option>
</select>
```

Notice that I removed item.id and replaced it with itemSource[item] as the property id won't always exist.

Basically, your custom component needs a property to work with. if it's an object, it displays the values of its properties where the properties are the ids.
If it's an array, it converts it to an object and lists the values where the indexes are the ids (ngValue)